# Adding a textview and imageview to a linearlayout created dynamically in android

Tags: android, uiimageview, textview, android-linearlayout

I need to place a `textview` and `imageview` to a `linearlayout`. The content of the text is a string array.I couldn't get the text in the layout, everything else is fine
My code is :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView topicText = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout textLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
textLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
textLinear.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_background_item));
topicText.setId(i);
topicText.setTextSize((float) 19.2);
topicText.setText((CharSequence) mStringArray[i]);
topicText.setTextColor(000000);
topicText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon,0);
topicText.setLayoutParams(lp);
topicText.setTag(i);
textLinear.addView(topicText);
this.topLayout.addView(textLinear);
```

Comment: i added the linearlayout to the parent

Comment: So your question is how to get values from string array in resources?

Comment: yeah need to display the text and image for this linear layout created, but unfortunately text is not displayed :(

Comment: How you populate your array?

Comment: got the solution..a simple mistake, changed the textcolor and finally success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have really added TextView to LinearLayout. but your TextView text color is 0 which means transparent color. thus even TextView is added, it makes you to feel that TextView is not there as it's color is transparent. change text color to another color like BLACK (0xFF000000). may be this is the mistake you done...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exact answer:)